# I want to run task everyday, 00:00 (discord.py)

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, discord.py

I put codes together to run task in everyday, every 00:00 (just time when day changes). But this gives me two errors for one line.
`coma_schedule.change_interval(hours=interval.hours, minutes=interval.minutes, seconds=interval.seconds)`

```
AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'hours'
AttributeError: type object 'coma_schedule' has no attribute 'change_interval'
```

Well, since my codes are from `discord.py`'s official Discord server's `tag`(similar to sniffet I guess) and It should be working. I don't get why this give me errors.

(almost) Full code

```py
import discord
import datetime
import asyncio
import psycopg2 as pg2
from discord.ext import commands, tasks


class coma_schedule(commands.Cog, name='coma_schedule'):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        print('[COMA SCHEDULER] coma scheduler is ready')
        self.bot = bot
        self.coma_schedule.start()

    def cog_unload(self):
        self.coma_schedule.cancel()

    @tasks.loop(hours=24)
    async def coma_schedule(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        nextday = now + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        # Do my stuff
        # Do my stuff ends

        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        interval = nextday - now
        coma_schedule.change_interval(hours=interval.hours, minutes=interval.minutes, seconds=interval.seconds)

    @coma_schedule.before_loop
    async def coma_schedule_before(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        nextday = datetime.datetime.now()
        nextday.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
        if nextday < now:
            nextday.replace(day=now.day + 1)
        await asyncio.sleep((nextday - now).total_seconds())


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(coma_schedule(bot))
```

I don't know what should I fix only with that `AttributeError` so I really need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'hours'`, you substracted a `datetime` object from another, so you get a `timedelta` object in return. This object has no `hours` attribute: only `days`, `seconds` and `microseconds`. Hence the `AttributeError`.

In your case, though, since it's a `timedelta` of exactly one day, the hours and minutes will be the same on `now` and `nextday`, so you can get them from there.

For your second issue, it's less clear, but I believe you're trying to access a method of the name `change_interval`. If so, you're trying to access a function from the name of your object (`coma_schedule`), not the current instance (`self`). Since the function you're trying to access isn't static, you can't access it from `abc`: you want to call `self.change_interval` instead.

Comment: At last, I ended up to change some code, to be
`self.coma_scheduler.change_interval(hours=intervals.seconds/3600, minutes=intervals.seconds/60,  seconds=intervals.seconds)
`
someone in the Discord server said that I might shadowing variable so I changed class name and function name. 
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @tetratheta FYI, I thought you were shadowing ```coma_schedule``` at first as well since it's both a class and method name, but you weren't. Still, it's a good idea not to have classes that contain methods named exactly like them